# Is there a way to use "npx react-native link" with expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to link some files of my project using "npx react-native link", but it won't let me. When I used react-native, it did let me. But now, with expo, I can't.

If you need more details, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

The `react-native link` command is for react-native projects that are created with `react-native init` command to link native dependencies.

For projects that were initialized in expo, there are limitations and specific instructions to linking native code. The docs for this can be found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/).